# Android access XML responds

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-xml

I write an android client, and need to access Web server. Then back to XML, android client read XML data. Access web URL like: http://xxxx.com/Mobile/MobileAjax.aspx?pAjaxType=Login&pUserID=adminsys&pPwd=123456

Access XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LoginInfo>
<Islogin>true</Islogin>
<UserID>AdminSys</UserID>
<UserName>admin</UserName>
<OrgID>100</OrgID>
<OrgName>organizer</OrgName>
</LoginInfo>
```

How to write the code about get XML and analyze XML information?

Comment: There are several examples already available. For instance: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/. Do a little search before asking people to do it for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android xml parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492034/android-xml-parsing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This same question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366742/xml-parser-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492034/android-xml-parsing)

There three main type of parsing are there for XML.

1. Pull parser
2. Sax parser
3. Dom parser

Here you can find example for [Pull parser](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidXML/article.html#xmlpullparser)

Here you can find example for [Sax parser](http://matrix-examplecode.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-sax-parser-example.html)

Here you can find example for [All three](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)