# Parsing XML to Java List

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, saxparser

I want to parse below xml file which has huge data, Here is my xml.

what is the best way to parse from XML to java List? can i use SAXParser for parsing the XML or any other efficient way? I expect , i would have data more than 1 million.

```
<root>
    <Company>
        <name>TATA</name>
        <Location>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>India</name>
            <branchesList>
                <branches>
                <name>Chennai</name>
                <id>Ch-1</id>
                <status>Active</status>
            </branches>
            <branches>
                <name>Hyderabad</name>
                <id>Hy-1</id>
            <status>In-Active</status>
            </branches>
            <branches>
                <name>Delhi</name>
                <id>De-1</id>
                <status>Active</status>
            </branches>
        </branchesList>
        </Location>
         <Location>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>USA</name>
            <branchesList>
                <branches>
                <name>NewYork</name>
                <id>Nw-1</id>
                <status>Active</status>
            </branches>
            <branches>
                <name>NewJersy</name>
                <id>Ne-1</id>
            <status>In-Active</status>
            </branches>
            <branches>
                <name>Denver</name>
                <id>De-1</id>
                <status>Active</status>
            </branches>
        </branchesList>
        </Location>
      </Company>

    </root>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing large XML documents in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132390/parsing-large-xml-documents-in-java)

Comment: Why java list? You might as well build a dom tree and query with xpath...

Comment: This SO post may help you finding a better/performant solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791600/can-sax-parsers-use-xpath-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15132587/967768)

It recommends using SAXParser for big XMLs.

As of having 1 million + Strings in a list in java, in principle there is no issue. You could have as many as `Integer.MAX_VALUE-5` iirc.

Documentation for SAXParser is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) and is quite complete. You should have no issue taking the elements you want and putting them in a list.

Finally, if you want to have more than a simple list of strings in memory, I would look at other collections like `Dictionary`.

Comment: The parsing itself is not the real problem here. Is the list the user wants to have in memory, which doesn't sound that much either but in any case that is the part to worry not sax parser's use of memory.

Comment: Yes you are right, the "title" part of his question mentions having it into a list.

Comment: I tried to answer all the parts of his question. Thanks for your feedback @David Hofmann

Comment: Thanks let me try as suggested