# What is the best solution for reading a large xml document?

Tags: java, xml

> Avoid large objects in memory, or using String to hold large documents which should be handled with better tools. For example, don't read a large XML document into a String, or DOM.

The above quote is from an article.  What is the best solution for reading a large xml document?

Comment: SAX Parsing will solve your problem.
try to read below link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825206/why-is-sax-parsing-faster-than-dom-parsing-and-how-does-stax-work][1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use SAX or StAX parser it will not hold all contents of xml in memory.

> Unlike the DOM parser, the SAX parser does not create an in-memory
>   representation of the XML document and so is faster and uses less
>   memory. Instead, the SAX parser informs clients of the XML document
>   structure by invoking callbacks, that is, by invoking methods on a
>   org.xml.sax.helpes.DefaultHandler instance provided to the parser.

Here is an example implementation:

```
SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
DefaultHandler handler = new MyHandler();
parser.parse("file.xml", handler);
```

Where in

> MyHandler

you define the actions to be taken when events like start/end of document/element are generated.(below is just elementary implementation)

```
class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
    }

    // To take specific actions for each chunk of character data (such as
    // adding the data to a node or buffer, or printing it to a file).
    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
    }

}
```

[this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html) is good article for samples of SAX and StAX parser

Answer (score 0):

use SAX or Stax parser. don't go with DOM or JAXB.